# differences in "to hit the road" in Spanish

Tags: expresiones

I see that both [SpanishDict](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/hit%20the%20road) and [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=hit%20the%20road) list ponerse en marcha and ponerse en camino as translations for "to hit the road". However, I've come across a sentence that uses lanzarse a la carretera and google translates that also to "hit the road". I'm wondering if there are any differences between these three phrases or whether they can be used interchangeably?

Comment: I think carretera would usually be a fairly important road whereas camino could just be a pedestrian track.

Comment: google translate et alia are not good at colloquial idioms. To hit the road is a colloquial idiom. This has zero to do with: lanzarse. ponerse en camino etc. To hit the road means: to leave a place and go on a trip/go traveling. You might see in Spanish, for this idea: largarse. Although that does not necessarily involve a trip. Me largo mañana para Madrid.,

Comment: Las primeras dos frases son metafóricas. Tu última frase es literal.